# How to draw shape and use as button in Shoes?

Tags: ruby, shoes

I am writing a calendar GUI in Ruby using [Shoes](http://shoesrb.com). Everything was going well with all of it's features, until I got to the part where I wanted to style the boxes I had created. I was using basic Shoes::Shapes at first for placeholder, but after reading through the documentation I decided this was going to be undoable. I then tried to do the border solution, but that too didn't seem to work very well. Here is a very basic example of what I am trying to achieve. [image: example]

The boxes must function as both clickable (so a button), and an element who's contents can be changed. What, if any, is the best way to achieve this in Shoes? Will I have to ditch Shoes and pursue some other GUI framework instead?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. For some reason, I didn't see it (or it didn't register) when I originally viewed this page. The answer can be found [here](http://shoesrb.com/manual/Element.html)